# Выполнить побайтово сравнение двух текстовых файлов.

Tags: c++, c

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

int counter = 0;
FILE *file1, *file2;


    if ((file1 = fopen("file1.txt", "rb")) != NULL)
    {
        if ((file2 = fopen("file2,txt", "rb")) != NULL)
        {
            bool ch1, ch2;
            do
            {
                ch1 = getc(file1);
                ch2 = getc(file2);
                if (ch1 != ch2)
                {
                    counter++;
                    printf("Файлы не идентичны!!!\nНомер байта в котором они расходятся %i", counter);
                }
            } while (ch1 != EOF);
            if (counter == 0)
                printf("Два файла полностью идентичны");
        }
        else
            printf("Не удается открыть второй файл!");
    }
    else
        printf("Не удается открыть первый файл!");


_getch();
}
```

Выполнить побайтовое сравнение двух текстовых файлов. Вывести на экран строки, в которых обнаружены расхождение. Очистить один из файлов, если они полностью совпадают.

выбивает ошибку, не понимаю в чем дело.

Comment: Мы должны гадать, какая у вас ошибка? И как вы собираетесь вывести строки двоичных файлов на экран?

Comment: И на каком языке вы пишите программу: на C или C++?

Comment: А второй файл точно называется `file2,txt`? Почему на `EOF` проверяется только первый файл? И всегда ли корректна эта проверка для типа `bool`?

Answer (score 1):

Если не принять во внимание опечатку

```
if ((file2 = fopen("file2,txt", "rb")) != NULL)
                        ^^^
```

то независимо от того, на каком языке написана ваша программа, C или С++, уже первое сравнение

```
if (ch1 != ch2)
```

может дать неверный результат, так как переменные `ch1` и `ch2` объявлены, как имеющие тип `bool`

```
bool ch1, ch2;
```

Поэтому в условии предложения `if` они будут преобразованы либо к 1 либо к 0. То есть вы не будете сравнивать считанные символы, а будете сравнивать отличны ли один символ от 1, а другой от 0 или наоборот.

Более того условие цикла

```
while (ch1 != EOF);
```

у вас всегда будет истинно, так как при обратном преобразовании `ch1` в целочисленный тип, вы никога не получите `-1`, которая обычно соответствует `EOF`, а получите, опять-таки,. либо 0, либо 1. То есть цикл у вас будет бесконечным.

Если вы сравниваете текстовые файлы, то лучше открывать их в текстовом режиме и сравнивать построчно.

Ежели сравнивать файлы как бинарные, то вам надо будет подсчитывать символы перехода на новую строку `'\n'`, чтобы сообщить, в какой строке обнаружено расхождение.